# Cycle looping of array elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In my page I've got a series of divs contained in a wrapper:

```
 <div id="superiordiv">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
  <div class="child">div4</div>
  <div class="child">div5</div>
  <div class="child">div6</div>
  <div class="child">div7</div>
  <div class="child">div8</div>
  <div class="child">div9</div>
  <div class="child">div10</div>
  <div class="child">div11</div>
  <div class="child">div12</div>
  <div class="child">div13</div>
  <div class="child">div14</div>
  <div class="child">div15</div>
  <div class="child">div16</div>
  <div class="child">div17</div>
  <div class="child">div18</div>
  <div class="child">div19</div>
  <div class="child">div20</div>
  <div class="child">div21</div>
  <div class="child">div22</div>
  <div class="child">div23</div>
  <div class="child">div24</div>
</div>
```

With jQuery I want to cycle them and make some actions with elements separately.

With this method I collect all these elements in an array then I cycle them showing 3 at times.

```
var $elements = $("#superiordiv").find('.child');
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply($elements);


$elements.hide();
var t = setInterval(function () {

  $elements.hide();
  var current = elements.slice(0,3);
  $(current).show();

  elements.push(elements.shift());

}, 1000 );
```

when I reach the end of the elements

> div22,div23,div24

I want start over and obtain this result div

> div23,div24,div1 | div24,div1,div2

Naturally `<div class="child">div1</div>` comes first than divs `<div class="child">div23</div> and <div class="child">div24</div>`

So the result I obtain is this:

> div1,div23,div24 | div1,div2,div24

How can I get the previous result ? Is there some sort of trick I can apply to my code?

I post a [Codepen of the source](https://codepen.io/Giova/pen/pRyKRz)

```js
var $elements = $("#superiordiv").find('.child');
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply($elements);


$elements.hide();
var t = setInterval(function() {

  $elements.hide();
  var current = elements.slice(0, 3);
  $(current).show();

  elements.push(elements.shift());

}, 1000);
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="superiordiv">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
  <div class="child">div4</div>
  <div class="child">div5</div>
  <div class="child">div6</div>
  <div class="child">div7</div>
  <div class="child">div8</div>
  <div class="child">div9</div>
  <div class="child">div10</div>
  <div class="child">div11</div>
  <div class="child">div12</div>
  <div class="child">div13</div>
  <div class="child">div14</div>
  <div class="child">div15</div>
  <div class="child">div16</div>
  <div class="child">div17</div>
  <div class="child">div18</div>
  <div class="child">div19</div>
  <div class="child">div20</div>
  <div class="child">div21</div>
  <div class="child">div22</div>
  <div class="child">div23</div>
  <div class="child">div24</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are hiding and showing the element because the `div1` written before `div24` so `div1` is appear first.

Try using `append` and `remove`

```js
var $elements = $("#superiordiv").find('.child');
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply($elements);
$elements.remove();
var t = setInterval(function() {

  $elements.remove();
  var current = elements.slice(0, 3);
  console.log(current);
  $('#superiordiv').append(current);

  elements.push(elements.shift());

}, 1000);
```

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="superiordiv">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
  <div class="child">div4</div>
  <div class="child">div5</div>
  <div class="child">div6</div>
  <div class="child">div7</div>
  <div class="child">div8</div>
  <div class="child">div9</div>
  <div class="child">div10</div>
  <div class="child">div11</div>
  <div class="child">div12</div>
  <div class="child">div13</div>
  <div class="child">div14</div>
  <div class="child">div15</div>
  <div class="child">div16</div>
  <div class="child">div17</div>
  <div class="child">div18</div>
  <div class="child">div19</div>
  <div class="child">div20</div>
  <div class="child">div21</div>
  <div class="child">div22</div>
  <div class="child">div23</div>
  <div class="child">div24</div>
</div>
```